# Sync sheet data with calendar after making changes to it locally (thru gDrive)

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible after making some changes to sheet document **on PC** and successful sync to google drive, to run specific script (on Google side, kind of cron in unix) to import changes from this sheet to Google Calendar service?
P.S. I already know how to import changes from Sheets to Calendar, the question is about automatic run of this import process on document change(edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this documentation about [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) which  let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event occurs. It is similar to [simple triggers for Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started) like `onOpen()`, but they can respond to additional events, and they behave differently.

You can use an [installable edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers) that runs when a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet.

Based from this [forum](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-automatically-run-a-Google-Script-Function-when-my-Spreadsheet-is-edited):

> The `onEdit()` trigger is the way to go. Here's a simple example
>   pulled straight from the documentation:
>
> ```
> function onEdit(event)
> {
>   var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
>   var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
>   r.setComment("Last modified: " + (new Date()));
> }
> ```
>
> Inside the body of the function you can do a variety of things. If you
>   need access to authorized services (such as Gmail, Calendar, etc) then
>   you'll need to create an installable trigger instead.

Hope this helps!